# XSLT, do transformation for child node when the parent node attribute matches the value of an attribute of another node

Tags: xslt

I have a source xml:

```
<root>
  <DataDictionary>
    <DataField name="CLASS">
      <Value value="0" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
    </DataField>
    <DataField name="COUNTRY_CODE">
      <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="3" property="valid"/>
    </DataField>
    <DataField name="MARITAL_STATUS">
      <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="3" property="valid"/>
    </DataField>
  </DataDictionary>
  <RegressionModel targetVariable="CLASS">
    <ParamMatrix>
      <PCell name="COUNTRY_CODE" targetCategory="0" coefficient="12"/>
      <PCell name="MARITAL_STATUS" targetCategory="0" coefficient="34"/>
    </ParamMatrix>
  </RegressionModel>
<root>
```

After transformation, I would like to have:

```
<root>
  <DataDictionary>
    <DataField name="CLASS">
      <Value value="0" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
    </DataField>
    <DataField name="COUNTRY_CODE">
      <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="3" property="valid"/>
    </DataField>
    <DataField name="MARITAL_STATUS">
      <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
      <Value value="3" property="valid"/>
    </DataField>
  </DataDictionary>
  </Schema>
  <RegressionModel targetVariable="CLASS">
    <ParamMatrix>
      <PCell name="COUNTRY_CODE" targetCategory="0" coefficient="12"/>
      <PCell name="MARITAL_STATUS" targetCategory="0" coefficient="34"/>
    </ParamMatrix>
  </RegressionModel>

  <!--other transformations -->

  <RegressionTable targetVariable="CLASS" targetCategory="1" />
  <RegressionTable targetVariable="CLASS" targetCategory="2" />
<root>
```

There are other transformations which I am not listing here. What I have problem with are the 2 'RegressionTable' elements at the end of the file. The logic used to build the transformation is:

1. get the value of the attribute 'targetVariable' of element 'RegressionModel'. In this case, value is "CLASS".
2. for element 'DataDictionary/DataField' where attribute 'name' has the same value as step 1, go through the child nodes 'Value'
3. for each 'Value' element from step2, if its attribute 'value' does ***not equal*** to the value of attribute 'targetCategory' of the first 'RegressionModel/ParamMatrix/PCell', we add an element

the element look like:

```
<RegressionTable 
    targetVariable=DataDictionary/DataField/@name 
    targetCategory=DataDictionary/DataField/Value/@value />
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I got lost in your description. You want to go over the `Value` nodes listed under `<DataField name="CLASS">` (because `<RegressionModel targetVariable="CLASS">`) and compare them to the value of the first `PCell`? Even though the first `PCell` is named `COUNTRY_CODE`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes. I know it sounds strange. But this is actually part of a logistic regression model file. In the PCell, the targetCategory value is the target value that is to be predicted using this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your instructions verbatim (AFAICT):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="dataField" match="DataField" use="@name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RegressionModel" mode="reg-tab"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RegressionModel" mode="reg-tab">
    <xsl:variable name="targetVariable" select="@targetVariable" />
    <xsl:variable name="targetCategory" select="ParamMatrix/PCell[1]/@targetCategory" />
    <xsl:for-each select="key('dataField', $targetVariable)/Value[@value != $targetCategory]">
        <RegressionTable targetVariable="{$targetVariable}" targetCategory="{@value}" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <DataDictionary>
      <DataField name="CLASS">
         <Value value="0" property="valid"/>
         <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
         <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
      </DataField>
      <DataField name="COUNTRY_CODE">
         <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
         <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
         <Value value="3" property="valid"/>
      </DataField>
      <DataField name="MARITAL_STATUS">
         <Value value="1" property="valid"/>
         <Value value="2" property="valid"/>
         <Value value="3" property="valid"/>
      </DataField>
   </DataDictionary>
   <RegressionModel targetVariable="CLASS">
      <ParamMatrix>
         <PCell name="COUNTRY_CODE" targetCategory="0" coefficient="12"/>
         <PCell name="MARITAL_STATUS" targetCategory="0" coefficient="34"/>
      </ParamMatrix>
   </RegressionModel>
   <RegressionTable targetVariable="CLASS" targetCategory="1"/>
   <RegressionTable targetVariable="CLASS" targetCategory="2"/>
</root>
```

which is not exactly the result you show.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks, the use of reg-tab is new to me. A further question though, what if the <RegressionTable> elements should be created inside the 'RegressionModel' element?

Comment: thanks, the use of reg-tab is new to me. A further question though, what if the <RegressionTable> elements should be created inside the 'RegressionModel' element, after some transformation has occurred in the same 'RegressionModel' element?  can <xsl:apply-templates select="rs:GeneralRegressionModel" mode="reg-tab"/> be used inside <xsl:apply-templates select="rs:GeneralRegressionModel" /> ?

Comment: "*what if the <RegressionTable> elements should be created inside the 'RegressionModel' element*" Then it would not be necessary to process `RegressionModel` twice - and there would be a single, modeless template matching it and handling both the "*some transformation*" and the creation of the <RegressionTable> elements.

Comment: I will add my xslt code to my original post. Could you please take a look for me why this last transformation is ignored? Thanks

Comment: I am afraid I can't do that. You did the right thing when you simplified the case in the original question. Your added XSLT is too long and too different to qualify as a follow-up.

Comment: I finally made it to work. It did not work before because I used namespace declaration 'rs', and I missed to add 'rs:' before one element :-( --- key('dataField', $targetVariable)/rs:Value    Thank you so much for always elegant solutions!